# Python Selenium How to Input Login ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am new to selenium and need help to input login information into a site. The Chrome developer page renders:

```
<input name="ctl00$cntPlcHldrContent$txtUsrID" type="text" maxlength="16" id="ctl00_cntPlcHldrContent_txtUsrID" class="textbox" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

The site I am trying to login is
and the code I use is as follows:

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='ctl00$cntPlcHldrContent$txtUsrID']")))
username.click()
username.clear()
username.send_keys(USERNAME)
```

However the error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.py", line 32, in <module>
    username = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='ctl00$cntPlcHldrContent$txtUsrID']")))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether input element inside iframe?? You can check in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login is behind an iframe element. Thanks @KunduK. I manage to switch to it and it worked.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_vIXmop9dU8iD_"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/iframe'))

username = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_cntPlcHldrContent_txtUsrID")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_cntPlcHldrContent_txtUsrPwd")))

username.click()
username.clear()
username.send_keys(USERNAME)
password.click()
password.clear()
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
```